# tf2 convert transform to msg

Tags: ros, transform, roscpp, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should be a simple task:

```
#include <tf2/transform_datatypes.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h>

...
geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transform = anything;
geometry_msgs::PoseStamped pose;
tf2::convert(transform, pose);
...
```

So this code should convert the TransformStamped to PoseStamped (similar to tf::poseTFtoMsg).
But the compiler complains that toMsg and fromMsg aren't defined. IMO there are some includes missing. Where are toMsg and fromMsg for PoseStamped defined?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206962/tf2-convert-transform-to-msg/) by [Michael Stoll](https://answers.ros.org/users/12221/michael-stoll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-04-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are getting errors with missing definitions that means that you have do not have the correct headers included.

There are tutorials here: http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Migration/DataConversions

However you'll find that PoseStamped and TransformStamped do not have conversions defined between them because they contain different data. The convert method is designed for converting homogeneous datatypes between representations in different libraries. Any conversion must be reversible for it to work in this framework.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tf2::convert is not designed to convert one message to a different message.
http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/tf2/html/impl_2convert_8h_source.html

Technically, geometry_msgs::Transform and geometry_msgs::Pose are different data, though I frequently find that I want to convert between the two. You can overload "convert" or use a different function name in a helper file.

```
namespace tf2
{
    inline
    void convert(const geometry_msgs::Transform& trans, geometry_msgs::Pose& pose)
    {
        pose.orientation = trans.rotation;
        pose.position.x = trans.translation.x;
        pose.position.y = trans.translation.y;
        pose.position.z = trans.translation.z;
    }

    inline
    void convert(const geometry_msgs::Pose& pose, geometry_msgs::Transform& trans)
      {
        trans.rotation = pose.orientation;
        trans.translation.x = pose.position.x;
        trans.translation.y = pose.position.y;
        trans.translation.z = pose.position.z;
    }

    inline
    void convert(const geometry_msgs::TransformStamped& trans, geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& pose)
    {
        convert(trans.transform, pose.pose);
        pose.header = trans.header;
    }

    inline
    void convert(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& pose, geometry_msgs::TransformStamped& trans)
    {
        convert(pose.pose, trans.transform);
        trans.header = pose.header;
    }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [bsaund](https://answers.ros.org/users/29303/bsaund/) with karma: 161 on 2017-09-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2